# Yum Install meaning @

Tags: centos, yum

I do this command

```
Yum list all | grep sclo-php
```

this is what I got out:

```
sclo-php71-php-imap.x86_64        7.1.8-1.el7      @centos-sclo-sclo
```

My question is what is @ when output from my console?

Comment: Please don't sabotage your question.

Comment: @OskarSkog i have do a mistake when i want to update my question, how can i do to revert?

Comment: @Mercer I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@centos-sclo-sclo` is the repository name from which the package was installed.

`yum list all` list all installed and available packages. The far right field is the repository name. If the repository name **starts with @**, it means the packages is **installed**.